# How to replace punctuation with space python

Tags: python

I use this code for removing `punctuation` from `sentence` but Now I need to replace the `punctuation` with `space`

```
sentence = 'hi,how are you?'
temp = ''.join([''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in sentence])

outPut => `hihow are you`
```

I need to be like this

```
outPut => `hi how are you`
```

I need the fastest way to do that

Comment: Can you give example input and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your generator comprehension, by using [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```py
import string

sentence = 'hi,how are you?'
temp = ''.join(c if c not in string.punctuation else ' ' for c in sentence)
print(temp) # hi how are you
```

Answer (score 2):

Python has a built-in function for replacing.

```
sentence = 'The.quick.brown.fox.jumps.over.the.lazy.dog'

print(sentence.replace('.',' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex approach here:

```py
import string
import re

sentence = 'hi,how are you?'
output = re.sub(r'[' + string.punctuation + r']+', ' ', sentence).strip()
print(output)  # hi how are you
```